# GAE NDB with Endpoints Proto Datastore:How do i access and modify the response data in google endpoint api for query with ndb model with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-python27

I want to manipulate the query response of google endpoint model in python.

I tried this but only fetches query response in json

```
@Gadget.query_method(collection_fields=('locationPostCode',),path='gadgets', name='gadget.list', query_fields=('ownerID', 'category', 'locationCity','pageToken'))

def GadgetList(self, query):

  return query
```

I want that api fetches postcodes and convert into array format and one by one postcode value pass to the other api.

I already try to print the response and convert the response in array format by `json.load()` but nothing work please provide me the solution.

please help me to solve this.